# Trying to get encoding from a webpage Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, character-encoding, beautifulsoup, html

Im trying to retrieve the charset from a webpage(this will change all the time). At the moment Im using beautifulSoup to parse the page and then extract the charset from the header. This was working fine until I ran into a site that had.....

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

My code up until now and which was working with other pages is:

```
    def get_encoding(soup):
        encod = soup.meta.get('charset')
        if encod == None:
            encod = soup.meta.get('content-type')
            if encod == None:
                encod = soup.meta.get('content')
    return encod
```

Would anyone have a good idea about how to add to this code to retrieve the charset from the above example. Would tokenizing it and trying to retrieve the charset that way be an idea? and how would you go about it without having to change the whole function? 
Right now the above code is returning "text/html; charset=utf-8" which is causing a LookupError because this is an unknown encoding.

Thanks

The final code that I ended up using:

```
    def get_encoding(soup):
        encod = soup.meta.get('charset')
        if encod == None:
            encod = soup.meta.get('content-type')
            if encod == None:
                content = soup.meta.get('content')
                match = re.search('charset=(.*)', content)
                if match:
                    encod = match.group(1)
                else:
                    dic_of_possible_encodings = chardet.detect(unicode(soup))
                    encod = dic_of_possible_encodings['encoding'] 
    return encod
```

Comment: I have used chardet but I wanted to be 100% accurate and so want to try and grab the encoding from the page itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re
def get_encoding(soup):
    if soup and soup.meta:
        encod = soup.meta.get('charset')
        if encod == None:
            encod = soup.meta.get('content-type')
            if encod == None:
                content = soup.meta.get('content')
                match = re.search('charset=(.*)', content)
                if match:
                    encod = match.group(1)
                else:
                    raise ValueError('unable to find encoding')
    else:
        raise ValueError('unable to find encoding')
    return encod
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Really need to learn myself some regex.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `soup.meta` only returns the first `meta`-tag found in the soup. Here is @Fruit's answer extended to find the `charset` in any `meta`-tag within the given `html`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_encoding(soup):
    encoding = None
    if soup:
        for meta_tag in soup.find_all("meta"):
            encoding = meta_tag.get('charset')
            if encoding: break
            else:
                encoding = meta_tag.get('content-type')
                if encoding: break
                else:
                    content = meta_tag.get('content')
                    if content:
                        match = re.search('charset=(.*)', content)
                        if match:
                           encoding = match.group(1)
                           break
    if encoding:
        # cast to str if type(encoding) == bs4.element.ContentMetaAttributeValue
        return str(encoding).lower()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(get_encoding_from_meta(soup))
```